# Get list of all the implementations of an interface using factory pattern in php

Tags: php, object, design-patterns, interface, factory

I have an interface called MyModule.php and few classes Module1.php,Module2.php,Module3.php which implements the MyModule interface.
The objective is to use a factory pattern approach to get a list of all the implementations of the MyModule interface.
Should I create a MyFactory.php class in the same folder and use something like

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$implementsMyModule = array();
foreach($classes as $cs) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($cs);
    if($reflect->implementsInterface('MyModule')) 
        $implementsMyModule[] = $cs;
 }
```

Is this the correct way to do this?